# Switch case syntax in Java

Tags: java, syntax, switch-statement

can't seem to find the syntax mistake in this switch statement. Any help is much appreciated.

**Source code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SwitchCasing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = sc.nextLine();
        try {
            int number = Integer.parseInt(input);

            switch(number) {
                case 1:
                    if(number < 0) {
                        System.out.println("Number is smaller than 0.");
                        break;
                    }
                case 2: 
                    if(number > 0){
                        System.out.println("Number is greater than 0.");
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    System.out.println("Number is 0.");
            }
        } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println("Please insert a valid number.");
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

The output is always "Number is 0", no matter what value is entered. 
Thanks!

Comment: `if(number < 0)` will always be false

Comment: I don't understand - your code will only accept the number 1 or 2.  Anything else will fall into default.  Is that not what you want?

Comment: If *output is always "Number is 0"*, then your code compiles and runs, and you don't have any *syntax mistakes*. You do have logic mistakes, but that's different.

Comment: Actually, it's not a syntax error, but it is a syntax mistake. Misusing the label on the `case` and putting an `if` inside it is a mistake due to imperfect understanding of syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`case 1:` means that number *equals* 1. But since 1 is not less than 0 you'll never see "Number is smaller than 0.", and you won't break. (The `break` is inside the `if (number < 0)` part).

`case 2:` means that number *equals* 2. You'll enter this case if you enter a 2.

That leaves `default` for all other values you might enter, which I'm guessing are most of them.

You really don't want a `switch` in this situation. You should be using an `if-else` construct, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  String input = sc.nextLine();
  try{
    int number = Integer.parseInt(input);

    if(number < 0) {
        System.out.println("Number is smaller than 0.");
    } else if(number > 0) {
        System.out.println("Number is greater than 0.");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Number is 0.");
    }
  } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
    System.out.println("Please insert a valid number.");
  } finally {
    sc.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Those case labels aren't for you labeling purposes; they are for Java to compare `number` so it can execute the case.

It will start execution at the block for `case 1:` if `number` is `1`.  Because `1` isn't less than `0`, that block won't produce any output.

It will start execution at the block for `case 2:` if `number` is `2`.  Because `1` isn't less than `0`, that block will produce the output "Number is greater than 0.".

Any other number will go to the default case and produce the output "Number is 0.", even though your output is incorrect.

You can't test cases that way with a switch statement.  Change it to the equivalent if/else construct.

```
if(number < 0){
    System.out.println("Number is smaller than 0.");
}
else if(number > 0){
    System.out.println("Number is greater than 0.");
}
else {
    System.out.println("Number is 0.");
}
```

Comment: Ah, the question makes more sense now. I think I misinterpreted it. This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

As first, do you know you can do `int number = sc.nextInt();` you do not need to parse the input and it assures that the user gives you a int.

As for your switch case your break; are inside if statements so when the code reads break it breaks our of the loop containing it. In your case it breaks out of the if/else statement not the switch case.

Hope I could help!